# Error #Unhandled securityError accessing https://accounts.google.com

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to write a use-anywhere (web, air, mobile) OAuth library for AS3 that is flexible enough to use with any OAuth site or near OAuth.
My sample app I am writing authenticates with Google and I want to write an app that uses google drive.

At the moment the Air and mobile apps work fine but the web flash player app keeps giving me this error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://localhost:81/OAuthWebExample.swf cannot load data from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.
```

(I get the same error when on a non-localhost domain on port 80)

I have looked at https://accounts.google.com/crossdomain.xml which has:

```
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type" />
```

I am not sure what that means...

I am pretty sure that it is possible to get flash to talk to these google APIs. What can I do to get this to work?

(I'm not interested in the "work round" where you use feedburner or something similar to proxy these calls thanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have looked at https://accounts.google.com/crossdomain.xml

It's the master policy file and it doesn't grant permissions to the content of `accounts.google.com` domain (there isn't [allow-access-from](http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html#allow-access-from) nodes withing it), so flash player fires `securityError`

> I am not sure what that means...

[It means](http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html#site-control-permitted-cross-domain-policies):

> by-content-type: [HTTP/HTTPS only] Only policy files served with
>   Content-Type: text/x-cross-domain-policy are allowed

So it seems it's designed for sub-domain services and child `crossdomain.xml` files so you can't load data directly from `accounts.google.com`. I found the same issue with `Google OAuth` for flash [Google Oauth crossdomain.xml problem with Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466559/google-oauth-crossdomain-xml-problem-with-flex) and they have to use old `AuthSub` (it uses `accounts.googleapis.com` with proper [crossdomain.xml](https://accounts.googleapis.com/crossdomain.xml)) to solve the auth problem and it seem nothing were changed for the past two years.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Flash player security on compile, local or external.

The AIR applications can connect to external and local files, but a embedded swf can't do it

https://www.adobe.com/security/flashplayer/articles/localcontent/