# How do I get around this security error when drawing the stage into a BitmapData?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmapdata, stage

```
var snapshotWidth  : Number = stage.stageWidth;
var snapshotHeight : Number = stage.stageHeight;
try
{
    var snapshot : BitmapData = new BitmapData( snapshotWidth, snapshotHeight, false, 0 );
    snapshot.draw( stage );
}
catch( e: Error )
{
    snapshot = null;
}
```

This happens inside the main as, and I guarantee stage exists. I get this error:

```
Error #2123: Security sandbox violation:
BitmapData.draw: http://**********/game/flashmodule/Viewer.swf?version=1393597596
cannot access rtmpe://???????????/game/7?token=1ph72jFIDkxr-4jL&status=free.
No policy files granted access.
```

I have hidden the urls, they are different.

I have searched the internet and tried several policy files and put them in several places, added loadPolicyFile and even allowSecure and allowInsecure domains in the stage. Also allownetworking = "all";

Still this error occurs. I have a camera with a stream added to the stage, so its because of this, but how / where / with what exactly do I fix this? Perhaps the policy files I have tried are wrong.

Comment: Check this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392295/error-unhandled-securityerror-accessing-https-accounts-google-com/22056280#22056280][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392295/error-unhandled-securityerror-accessing-https-accounts-google-com/22056280#22056280

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are quite a few steps to making this work. After days of digging, I have found this neat tutorial explaining exactly what to do. Hope this will spare others the torment :D

http://www.thebluepipe.com/Developer/tutorials/as3/Crossdomain-Video-Snapshot-Fixing-BitmapData-draw-Security-Sandbox-Violation.html